# GLFW crash node process

Tags: c++, node.js, opengl, glfw

I'm implementing a mapping service, I use opengl to render 3d buildings. And I use glfw to get opengl context. In the mapping service, when there is a request to get a tile, the program create a invisiable GLFWwindow and use glfwMakeContextCurrent to make it current. The mapping core is written in c++ and wrapped to nodejs, the mapping service is a nodejs application. When there are many requests, the node process will crash, and with following error message:

```
Process:               node [18015]
Path:                  /usr/local/bin/node
Identifier:            node
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        node [18010]
Responsible:           Terminal [682]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-05-22 14:46:07.665 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        F6351CBD-E434-9570-1B79-B6E999DE965F


Time Awake Since Boot: 14000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        6

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff885b521a kevent + 10
1   node                            0x000000010043ce89 uv_run + 239
2   node                            0x00000001003f766a node::Start(int, char**) + 365
3   node                            0x0000000100001374 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff885af4de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff885ae64f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff92bc0eb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff92bc037b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff92bbfbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff92c77671 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   node                            0x0000000100447f1f uv__cf_loop_runner + 67
7   node                            0x000000010043c54a uv__thread_start + 25
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879e1268 _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879e11e5 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879df41d thread_start + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff885b5232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d91ca6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:: SamplerThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff885af51a semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   node                            0x00000001003ed7f8 v8::internal::MacOSSemaphore::Wait() + 24
2   node                            0x00000001002fba49 v8::internal::RuntimeProfilerRateLimiter::SuspendIfNecessary() + 121
3   node                            0x00000001003ed8c8 v8::internal::SamplerThread::Run() + 88
4   node                            0x00000001003ed08c v8::internal::ThreadEntry(void*) + 60
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879e1268 _pthread_body + 131
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879e11e5 _pthread_start + 176
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879df41d thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff885b4136 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   node                            0x0000000100445578 uv_cond_wait + 9
2   node                            0x0000000100445dfc worker + 207
3   node                            0x000000010043c54a uv__thread_start + 25
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879e1268 _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879e11e5 _pthread_start + 176
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879df41d thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   org.gdal.gdal                   0x000000010486fb4e SHPReadObject + 2698
1   org.gdal.gdal                   0x00000001047f7e41 OGRShapeLayer::FetchShape(int) + 45
2   org.gdal.gdal                   0x00000001047f7ff4 OGRShapeLayer::GetNextFeature() + 238
3   org.gdal.gdal                   0x0000000104778e1d OGRLayer::GetFeatureCount(int) + 37
4   org.gdal.gdal                   0x00000001047f8ef9 OGRShapeLayer::GetFeatureCount(int) + 235
5   mapping.node                    0x0000000103a38cbb map::OGRDataSourceWrapper::GetLayer(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int) + 2347 (ogr_data_source.cpp:111)
6   mapping.node                    0x0000000103a07e02 map::Map::Render__(map::Map::DrawType) + 1490 (map.cpp:271)
7   mapping.node                    0x0000000103a07267 map::Map::Render() + 647 (map.cpp:116)
8   mapping.node                    0x00000001039cb966 MappingWrapper::renderWorker(uv_work_s*) + 22 (mapping_wrapper.cc:542)
9   node                            0x0000000100445d87 worker + 90
10  node                            0x000000010043c54a uv__thread_start + 25
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879e1268 _pthread_body + 131
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879e11e5 _pthread_start + 176
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879df41d thread_start + 13

Thread 6 Crashed:
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff92cb5744 getAtomTarget + 84
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff92bfaad2 ___forwarding___ + 178
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff92bfa998 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
3   mapping.node                    0x0000000103d5b482 _glfwPlatformMakeContextCurrent + 50
4   mapping.node                    0x0000000103d5baf8 glfwCreateWindow + 712
5   mapping.node                    0x0000000103a2d718 map::OpenGLRender::InitOpenGL() + 40 (opengl_render.cpp:289)
6   mapping.node                    0x0000000103a2d618 map::OpenGLRender::Init(boost::shared_ptr<map::MapStyle>) + 24 (opengl_render.cpp:281)
7   mapping.node                    0x0000000103a074aa map::Map::Render() + 1226 (map.cpp:152)
8   mapping.node                    0x00000001039cb966 MappingWrapper::renderWorker(uv_work_s*) + 22 (mapping_wrapper.cc:542)
9   node                            0x0000000100445d87 worker + 90
10  node                            0x000000010043c54a uv__thread_start + 25
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879e1268 _pthread_body + 131
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879e11e5 _pthread_start + 176
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879df41d thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff885b4136 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   node                            0x0000000100445578 uv_cond_wait + 9
2   node                            0x0000000100445dfc worker + 207
3   node                            0x000000010043c54a uv__thread_start + 25
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879e1268 _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879e11e5 _pthread_start + 176
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879df41d thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff885b494a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879df40d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff885b494a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879df40d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff885b494a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879df40d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff885b494a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff879df40d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000000000c000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000001  rdx: 0x000000019a05b2c0
  rdi: 0x0000000c00000001  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x000000010681caa0  rsp: 0x000000010681ca90
   r8: 0x000000010681cb80   r9: 0x000000010681d000  r10: 0x0000000000000001  r11: 0x00007fff92bfa920
  r12: 0x000000010681cb00  r13: 0x00007fff895930c0  r14: 0x0000000100d8aa50  r15: 0x000000010681cb00
  rip: 0x00007fff92cb5744  rfl: 0x0000000000000287  cr2: 0x000000011888dd80

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     3


Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x10068bfff +node (???) <500822CB-7EA6-34D2-98D6-BF45AF81E1CB> /usr/local/bin/node
       0x100aec000 -        0x100afbfff  libSimplifiedChineseConverter.dylib (64) <468DE6E1-42B9-3751-ACA5-7D16C550FF84> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libSimplifiedChineseConverter.dylib
       0x100fc1000 -        0x100fc6fff +DTraceProviderBindings.node (0) <BCAA5EDB-BBF3-3556-98E6-6813F1A5BA72> /Users/USER/*/DTraceProviderBindings.node
       0x100fcf000 -        0x100fd4fff +DTraceProviderBindings.node (0) <1A6ED61C-E715-382E-BF88-2BDA307A51B4> /Users/USER/*/DTraceProviderBindings.node
       0x100fdd000 -        0x100fe1fff  com.apple.agl (3.3.0 - AGL-3.3.0) <83B4076C-BD87-3436-B59F-65184128FEC1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL
       0x100fe8000 -        0x100fedfff  com.apple.JavaVM (15.0.0 - 15.0.0) <67BD63C5-D82F-3A31-BC43-C8810356D524> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/JavaVM
       0x1039c4000 -        0x103df3ff7 +mapping.node (0) <6CCCCAEB-7D48-38D8-8C21-287A5C7E88BA> /Users/USER/*/mapping.node
       0x104174000 -        0x10424aff7 +org.osgeo.geos (3.4.2 - GEOS 3.4.3) <C28ECCD4-2212-3189-A25A-1A9BEFC07351> 
......

......

......

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 4
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 17548
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 168

VM Region Summary:

ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=243.9M resident=93.0M(38%) 

swapped_out_or_unallocated=150.9M(62%)

Writable regions: Total=1.2G written=174.7M(14%) resident=389.4M(32%) 

swapped_out=473.2M(39%) unallocated=830.0M(68%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL

===========                      =======

CG shared images                   4528K

CoreUI image data                     4K

Dispatch continuations             8192K

IOKit                             882.6M

Kernel Alloc Once                     8K

MALLOC                            277.4M

MALLOC (admin)                       32K

MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)            3768K        reserved VM address space 
(unallocated)
Memory Tag 255                    552.5M

Memory Tag 255 (reserved)          1920K        reserved VM address space 
(unallocated)
STACK GUARD                        56.0M

Stack                              12.7M

VM_ALLOCATE                        14.4M

__DATA                             19.6M

__GLSLBUILTINS                     2588K

__IMAGE                             528K

__LINKEDIT                         85.2M

__TEXT                            158.6M

__UNICODE                           552K

mapped file                       207.2M

shared memory                        68K

===========                      =======

TOTAL                               2.2G

TOTAL, minus reserved VM space      2.2G
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell what's going on here. But since you mentioned that this happens under high load we can conjecture a bit. What's probably going on here is, that you're simply running out of available system resources. Creating a window triggers a cascade of allocations and if too much of that happens in a short timeframe these allocations may fail or worse, trigger some bug.

My recommendation: Don't create a OpenGL for each and every tile. Create the window once at process start and a bunch of renderbuffers/textures to be used for drawing the tiles to. Then upon each request draw the tile into the preallocated resources and keep the resources around afterwards for the next tile. Don't even bother attempting to multithread the rendering; the OpenGL drivers will do that already internally for you and the driver developers have squeezed that dry; at best you're not going to slow the whole thing down. Just process the rendering requests serially. Optimization would focus on ordering the rendering so that resources required for rendering tiles would coalesce the rendering of that tiles.